# Analysing if the equality holds.

Tags: calculus

Lately In my textbook Ive been seeing a lot of inequalities, my problem is that I do not know what increases a term quickest apart from the number e. In this case how would you know that the left term is smaller then the right.

And what are the methods used to test similar problems to see if it holds?

$$\left| n x^{n-1}\right| \leq \frac{(\left| x\right| +H)^n}{H}$$, where H>0,

Comment: I don't really understand your first paragraph... If I got it right, note that $x^x$ increases faster than $e^x$ (and $x^{x^x}$ increases faster that $x^x$, etc...)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities for a chart of functions increasing at various rates.